# Programmatically get relational database source for SSAS objects across compatibility levels

Tags: ssas, adomd.net

I am attempting an analysis of my organisation's (rather old) SSAS cubes.

- Some of the cubes are multidimensional, compatibility level 1103.
- Some are tabular, compatibility level 1103.
- One is tabular, compatibility level 1200.

I am trying to relate objects in the cubes back to their SQL Server relational database source.

For the tabular (1200) cube I can simply use the following in a query window in SSMS:

`select [Name], [QueryDefinition] from $system.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS`

But this DMV is not useable for tabular (1103) or multidmensional cubes.

I can't find a [DMV within the [MS-SSAS] protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#rowsets-described-in-the-ms-ssas-sql-server-analysis-services-protocol) which provides similar information.

I have also attempted to use the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` within a C# (.net 8) application, but am still unable to figure out where to pull this information from.

In visual studio, the information can be found by opening (say) a multidimensional project and navigating as follows:

Solution Explorer, Dimensions, (click a dimension), data source view pane, click the DSV object, properties window, "Name" and "Schema" properties, which looks like this:

[image]